# Terraform - API returns data in a different order, so terraform sees a meaningless change?

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I am seeing terraform want to change resources for meaningless changes (often related to the ordering of list type things). For example below, This resource has not changed, just the ordering returned this particular run from the APIs.

**Can I change anything to prevent these sort of meaningless changes from showing up in plans and applys?** Application Gateway and it's many blocks are another example where I see this occurring.

```
# azurerm_web_application_firewall_policy.owasp_only will be updated in-place
  ~ resource "azurerm_web_application_firewall_policy" "owasp_only" {
        id                  = "/subscriptions/ReallingInterestingGUID/resourceGroups/rg-apim/providers/Microsoft.Network/ApplicationGatewayWebApplicationFirewallPolicies/ccr-owasp-only"
        name                = "ccr-owasp-only"
        tags                = {
            "created-by"      = bob.jones@jones.com
            "terraform-stack" = "api-gateway"
        }
        # (4 unchanged attributes hidden)

      ~ managed_rules {

          ~ managed_rule_set {
              ~ type    = "Microsoft_BotManagerRuleSet" -> "OWASP"
              ~ version = "0.1" -> "2.2.9"
            }
          ~ managed_rule_set {
              ~ type    = "OWASP" -> "Microsoft_BotManagerRuleSet"
              ~ version = "2.2.9" -> "0.1"
            }
       }

        # (1 unchanged block hidden)
    }
```

Comment: Have you made any manual changes to the resources? i.e. changes not with terraform?

Comment: Are you using the latest terraform and the latest provider too?

Comment: You may need to go back to older version of terraform since newer ones partially broke the ordering and "outside changes" logic: https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/28803 https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-aws/issues/11801

Comment: We have not made the changes that are shown in the plan. I will look at the issues linked. Thanks.

Comment: This is with Terraform 1.02 and AzureRM provider 2.67+

Answer (score 2):

In situations where a Terraform provider misunderstands API-based normalization as if it were drift, the general immediate answer is to change your configuration to match the normalized form that the remote system expects.

In your case, it seems like that would mean to swap the order of the two `managed_rule_set` blocks in your configuration, so that the ordering matches what the remote API considers to be the normalized representation.

Unfortunately these normalization rules are not universally well-documented in the remote system documentation, and so developers can miss them when implementing the Terraform provider integrations. The "real" answer to this would be to add the missing logic to the provider to allow it to recognize when two configurations are considered by the remote system to be equivalent, but of course that's not typically something you can do immediately and must instead wait for a new version of the provider which includes that additional logic. Making your configuration match what the remote system expects is therefore a more practical change you can make without changing your provider version.

Comment: I have accepted your answer, but unfortunately it doesn't seem to last. Making the change to the TF flie that terraform wants only seems to last for a limited time.. a little bit of time passes, and terraform wants to change it back, to the other order. It looks like the underlying APIs that are feeding terraform, deliver some of these blocks in different orders randomly...

Comment: I'd suggest opening an issue in [the Azure provider repository](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-azurerm) to see if they can add some extra logic so that the provider understands that the API seems to return these items in an inconsistent order between requests. Unfortunately if it isn't even _consistent_ then there will be no way to write a Terraform configuration that can fully converge without the provider's help to normalize this away.